# Dynamic ordering in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I've got to implement dynamic sorting in Entity Framework. I've found a piece of code that *almost* allows me to do this, but it doesn't work on navigation properties.

This works:

```
students.OrderBy("StudentName");
```

This does not:

```
students.OrderBy("Department.Ordinal");
```

This is the piece of code:

http://philsversion.com/2012/02/21/orderby-a-string-in-entity-framework/

How would I be able to change this to allow for the behavior I require?

Comment: Does `Dynamic` mean the object type of list `students` is not known?

Comment: Perhaps this: `students.OrderBy(s => s.Department.Ordinal);`?

Answer (score 0):

Check [System.Dynamic.Linq](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/). I'm using it and it handles more complex queries also with parameters.

Comment: Ok, this looks like a better solution!
My scenario is basically this: I have an entity which is normalized for versioning purposes. With ~2 million rows any solutions I try are beginning to get slow. I'll try this and see how it works out.

Comment: @AndrewC No solution you try is going to perform well if your database is not indexed properly. It has nothing to do with what method you use in Entity Framework. They will all boil down to roughly the same SQL code.

Comment: @Dismissile Yes, I am aware of this. The reason for the slowdown was actually due more to the function calls in the view.